# How to print only numbers in a given string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string called

```
var string ="Catch 22 Slaughterhouse 5 Fahrenheit 451"
```

I just want to print out the numbers from the string using the split function, array or loops in javascript

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try,

```
string.match(/\d+/g);
```

it returns an array of numbers matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to extract numbers from the string.

`\d` will match any number from the string. `+` will match one or more of the preceding characters.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aF3lO1/1)

```js
var str = "Catch 22 Slaughterhouse 5 Fahrenheit 451";

var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);

document.write(numbers);
```